# Why stepwise selection yields a model with larger AIC than another model?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, feature-selection, aic, stepwise-regression

I try to figure out the relationship between bike rental and some explanatory factor. The model I'm using is log negative binomial model.

Here is the data:

```
'data.frame':   731 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ instant   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ dteday    : Factor w/ 731 levels "2011/1/1","2011/1/10",..: 1 12 23 26 27 28 29 30 31 2 ...
 $ season    : Factor w/ 4 levels "spring","summer",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ yr        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ mnth      : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ holiday   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ weekday   : Factor w/ 7 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 ...
 $ workingday: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ weathersit: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ temp      : Factor w/ 3 levels "low","moderate",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ atemp     : num  0.364 0.354 0.189 0.212 0.229 ...
 $ hum       : Factor w/ 3 levels "dry","agreeable",..: 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ windspeed : Factor w/ 5 levels "B","C","D","E",..: 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 4 3 ...
 $ casual    : int  331 131 120 108 82 88 148 68 54 41 ...
 $ registered: int  654 670 1229 1454 1518 1518 1362 891 768 1280 ...
 $ cnt       : int  985 801 1349 1562 1600 1606 1510 959 822 1321 ...
```

The initial model I used as start point.

```
log_negativebinomial_fit <- glm(cnt~hum+atemp+weathersit+workingday+yr+season+I(atemp^2), data= bike, family = negative.binomial(theta=1,link="log"))
summary(log_negativebinomial_fit)

Call:  glm(formula = cnt ~ hum + atemp + weathersit + workingday + yr + 
    season + I(atemp^2), family = negative.binomial(theta = 1, 
    link = "log"), data = bike)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  humagreeable      humhumid         atemp   weathersit2  
     6.29407       0.02012      -0.07577       5.79034      -0.11419  
 weathersit3   workingday1           yr1  seasonsummer    seasonfall  
    -0.77882       0.05267       0.46632       0.27571       0.33942  
seasonwinter    I(atemp^2)  
     0.39563      -4.63977  

Degrees of Freedom: 729 Total (i.e. Null);  718 Residual
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      186.9 
Residual Deviance: 40.38    AIC: 13620
```

I used `step` in R to conduct variable selection for me, however, the result seems weird to me.

```
> step(log_negativebinomial_fit,
+      scope =list(upper=~windspeed*hum*atemp*weathersit*workingday*yr*season+I(atemp^2),lower=~1),
+      direction="both",
+      steps=200,trace=1
+      )
Start:  AIC=13622.04
cnt ~ hum + atemp + weathersit + workingday + yr + season + I(atemp^2)

                        Df Deviance   AIC
+ atemp:season           3   38.719 13586
+ hum:atemp              2   38.872 13588
+ yr:season              3   39.111 13596
+ windspeed              4   39.140 13599
+ workingday:season      3   39.567 13608
+ atemp:yr               1   39.771 13609
+ atemp:workingday       1   39.771 13609
+ hum:season             6   39.580 13614
+ hum:weathersit         1   40.019 13615
+ atemp:weathersit       2   40.061 13618
<none>                       40.385 13622
+ hum:workingday         2   40.267 13623
+ weathersit:season      6   39.951 13623
+ workingday:yr          1   40.383 13624
+ weathersit:yr          2   40.346 13625
+ hum:yr                 2   40.362 13625
+ weathersit:workingday  2   40.371 13626
- workingday             1   40.816 13631
- hum                    2   41.426 13644
- I(atemp^2)             1   47.792 13806
- weathersit             2   49.329 13843
- season                 3   50.991 13883
- atemp                  1   53.819 13958
- yr                     1   78.298 14574

Step:  AIC=13626.37
cnt ~ hum + atemp + weathersit + workingday + yr + season + I(atemp^2) + 
    atemp:season


Call:  glm(formula = cnt ~ hum + atemp + weathersit + workingday + yr + 
    season + I(atemp^2) + atemp:season, family = negative.binomial(theta = 1, 
    link = "log"), data = bike)

Coefficients:
       (Intercept)        humagreeable            humhumid               atemp  
          6.478458            0.008492           -0.093304            4.600862  
       weathersit2         weathersit3         workingday1                 yr1  
         -0.110714           -0.791679            0.050971            0.466812  
      seasonsummer          seasonfall        seasonwinter          I(atemp^2)  
          0.292224            1.458707            0.505776           -2.800671  
atemp:seasonsummer    atemp:seasonfall  atemp:seasonwinter  
         -0.169793           -2.000234           -0.288588  

Degrees of Freedom: 729 Total (i.e. Null);  715 Residual
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      186.9 
Residual Deviance: 38.72    AIC: 13630
```

The selection function based on AIC gives me a model with larger AIC? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `step` function does not generally yield the globally lowest AIC value as the function does not explore all possible subsets of the full model. It starts by adding or removing variables one by one and travels on a particular path that depends on its own past. Thus you might be able find a model with a lower AIC that did not happen to be in the particular path; there is nothing suprising with that.

However, stepwise variable selection has been heavily criticized in general and in several threads on Cross Validated (e.g. ["Algorithms for automatic model selection"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection/20856#20856)). You could benefit from using regularization (shrinkage) methods such as Lasso, ridge regression or elastic net regression instead.

While Ben Bolker mentions how (nearly) full subset selection can be done in R -- using package "glmulti" -- the problem of overfitting can be severe when full subset selection is used; see Hansen ["A winner’s curse for econometric models: on the joint distribution of in-sample fit and out-of-sample fit and its implications for model selection"](http://www.tse-fr.eu/sites/default/files/medias/stories/SEMIN_10_11/ECONOMETRIE/hansen.pdf) (2010). Hansen mentions regularization (such as Lasso, ridge or elastic net) as a possible remedy of the problem.

Comment: you might also want to check out the `glmulti` package, which attempts to do exhaustive or nearly exhaustive search of subsets.